# Should I flag this "dead end" question?

Tags: support, questions, flags, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051437/jquery-javascript-and-php-json-encode-of-multidimensional-array) is unanswerable on its current form. The issue is likely being caused by code that was not posted. The asker recognizes that, and *seems* to have lost interest in the question.

I voted to close as too localized, but I think it should eventually be deleted. Should I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on why you brought this up on Meta. Just flag the question for moderation attention, explain why you're flagging and if your flag is declined, well, there's your answer.

Comment: After less than half an hour?  No; that is simply too fast.  The guy may have had to answer a phone call, or speak with his boss, or wife, or ...

Comment: There should be a way to keep track of that question (beside starring it), so I'd remember to flag it later.

Comment: @bfavaretto Yes there is, you can bookmark it ;)

Comment: Why are you being so quick to declare the Op has lost interest? Even now is way too soon.

Comment: @YahooAnswersenthusiast, I guess I asked the wrong question here. I focused on that specific question, but the root motivation for asking is that I see a lot of questions on SO that won't help anybody, and I don't know what to do with them.

Comment: @bfavaretto Don't worry about them :) Concentrate on answering helpful questions, I really appreciate that you are interested in helping clean up the site and I know how frustrating it is to stumble upon questions that look dead and forgotten. For this specific question flagging would be too much, but I think we all see what your motivation was, and it was fine. Next time you can post a couple more questions, to better convey the message of the category of questions you have in mind and only make it about a single one if there's something _seriously wrong_ with it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Australia, and most of the times I ask a question I wouldn't get an answer for several hours, if not longer, because of the time delay from country to country. So basically with your question in mind, I would never get an answer as you or others could just flag them.

Keep in mind, maybe you may think this is "Un Answerable" in its current form, but maybe that's just a bold conclusion. Give it time - there's plenty of knowledge amongst the users here and there are other people who may have the answer.

Maybe request that the user provide more information to pinpoint their problem or give them directions on how to assist them.

Comment: You're right, as well as the others who commented above: it was too soon. I came to that conclusion when the OP commented "OK, thanks, must be some other problem in code that is calling that". But now the question has been closed, 4 more people considered it "too localized" too.